# How to add a custom filter for a chart?

Tags: web-part, filter, chart

I have a list which contains multiple columns. I have inserted the chart web part and it's showing the graph based on the column list. Now I want to add a custom drop down filter which contains column as options and it should display the graph according.
Any Solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about OOTB Chart Web Part. But it is possible with a 3rd party web part, [Plumsail Dashboard Designer](https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-dashboard-designer/). You can find a [sample with filtering](http://www.spchart.com/demo/helpdesk-dashboard) on their demo site.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this URL:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/e135d8ac-6d86-4b3e-ad27-0f91a54956c3?stoAI=10